# setRowAlignmentOptions CRASH, untrackable crash

Tags: ios, iphone, pspdfkit

[image]

How to track this leak. Since this is in PSPDFKit, I am not able to trace it. 
Exception break point don't work, I tried debug that, but some thread is breaking.
Can any one help how to trace this?

Comment: Contact the developers of PSPDFKit.

Comment: I solved this. :)  But I am not sure where this crash was generated :S  @steipete